# How to obtain percentiles with numerous groups from one dataset SAS?

Tags: statistics, sas, sas-macro, percentile

I have a list of 10000 observations, 1000 per code number:

```
proc surveyselect data=code_nums out=bootstrapped_code_names (keep=code_name qty replicate) sampsize=1825 method=urs outhits no print seed=0 rep=1000;
strata code_num;
run;

proc sql no print;
create table test as 
select code_num
,replicate
,sum(quantity) as total_qty
from bootstrapped_code_names
group code_name
order by total_qty

quit;

data work.test;
input code_num $9. replicate total_qty;
datalines;
123456780 87   0
123456780 34   0
12345678  837  2
123456780 475  4
123456780 74   5
123456780 507  9
123456780 28   9
123456788 76   3
```

.
.

How can I obtain the percentiles for each 1000 code number given this dataset. I then would like to have a dataset where it could look like:

```
data work.code2;
input code_num $9. replicate total_qty percentile;
datalines;
123456780 49  2  1
123456780 384 5  2
12345678  37  6  3
123456780 485 7  4
123456780 34  8  5
123456780 567 10 6
123456780 23  14 7
123456780 567 21 8
123456780 23  32 9
123456788 937 4  1
.
.
;
```

I tried using proc rank (see code below) and received the above output (example) but I noticed for the 80th (200th row for the first code number) wasn't correct...

```
proc rank data=combined out=combined_deciles groups=10;
by data_set_name;
var total_qty;
ranks PRanks;
run;

data want;
set combined_deciles;
by code_number Pranks;
if first.Pranks;
run;
```

Not sure to fix this, can someone help please

Comment: How was it not correct? I suspect you have ties in your data and how do you want to deal with ties?

Comment: @Reeza yes, there are ties in the data, in the total_qty column

Comment: @Reeza, regardless of ties, I would like to obtain whatever value is the 100th row to represent the 90th percentile and so on, for each group (code_num)

Comment: Then it seems you don't really want a rank/percentile, you just want to order the data. So you expect to see 0 to 9 for 10 ranks in all your data sets regardless if all values are the exact same. If this is correct, you should sort your data by the tot_qty and then add another variable that holds a running count. Use PROC RANK on the count. I would not call this a percentile in this case.

Comment: Actually looking at your data not sure that sort matters either. Can you provide a full reproducible example - one where the input aligns with the output?

Comment: @Reeza Ok, I only have one dataset. I would see 0 to 9 for each group in one dataset right? (the work.want) I do want to know what amount of qty is experience in that replicate at the 10th percentile for each group and so on all in one dataset, if possible. B/c that dataset will be used somewhere else

Comment: @Reeza yes will do

Comment: You say in "that replicate" but you're not ranking by replicate in any fashion here at all. The order is random. If you provided the data in a different order you'd get different output. Replicate plays no role in your current analysis.

Comment: @Reeza yes, true. I added more code to hopefully help...I am using a proc surveyselect function to produce the "replicate" variable.

Comment: I recall your previous questions but still doesn't relate to your current question.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your requirement isn't for a 'percentile' statistical definition but rank of the order of the rows.

In that case, something like this will work for you.

```
data work.code;
input code_num $9. replicate total_qty;
datalines;
123456780 87   0
123456780 34   0
123456780  837  2
123456780 475  4
123456780 74   5
123456780 507  9
123456780 28   9
123456780 87   0
123456780 34   0
123456780  837  2
123456780 475  4
123456780 74   5
123456780 507  9
123456780 28   9
123456788 76   3
123456788 76   3
123456788 76   3
123456788 76   3
123456788 76   3
;;;;


data _code /view = _code;
set code;
by code_num;

if first.code_num then count=1;
else count+1;
run;

proc rank data=_code out=want groups=10;
by code_num;
var count;
ranks countRank;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you, just tried it! I'm just stuck on how to obtain the 100th count, 200th count and so on for each group and form that into a dataset. @Reeza

Comment: What is the 100th count? 200th count?

Comment: which observations falls on these counts for each group. Like code_num 123456789, replicate 374, total_qty 1, count 100...code_num 123456789, replicate 374, total_qty 6, count 200.... A dataset that lists something like this for each code number

Comment: Then that's just the _code data set, you don't need proc rank you just want a count variable on the data set.

Comment: https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/sas/faq/how-can-i-create-an-enumeration-variable-by-groups/